Generalizing $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{( 1+x^2) ( 1+(2+x)^2) }\text{d}x+\int_{0}^{1}\frac1{(1+x^2)( 1+(2-x)^2)}\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{8} .$
It's easily seen that
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} 
\frac{1}{\left ( 1+x^2 \right )\left ( 1+(2+x)^2\right )  } 
\text{d}x+
\int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{1}{\left ( 1+x^2 \right )\left ( 1+(2-x)^2\right )  } 
\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{8} .
$$
I derived it by chance. But it's rare for these integrals combined to left the only $\pi$ factor, cancelling all the logarithmical terms. However, after some manipulations, I ran across the following integral, serving as a generalization to this:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} 
\frac{1}{\left ( 1+x^2 \right )\left ( 1+y^2 \right )
\left ( 1+(3+x+y)^2 \right )   }\text{d}x\text{d}y
+2\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{1}{\left ( 1+x^2 \right )\left ( 1+y^2 \right )
\left ( 1+(3-x+y)^2 \right )   }\text{d}x\text{d}y
+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{1}{\left ( 1+x^2 \right )\left ( 1+y^2 \right )
\left ( 1+(3-x-y)^2 \right )   }\text{d}x\text{d}y
=\frac{19\pi^2}{360}-\frac{\pi}{15}\ln(2).
$$
And also by multiple integration, it is equivalent to
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} 
e^{-3x}\sin(x)\left ( 
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-xy}}{1+y^2}\text{d}y 
+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{xy}}{1+y^2}\text{d}y \right )^2
\text{d}x=\frac{19\pi^2}{360}-\frac{\pi}{15}\ln(2).
$$
I believe the integral can somehow calculated but am still in a mess.  Could we ever verify the proposition, thence to generalized forms of such identities? I am appreciated for your sincere help and creative efforts.

To me, the last formulation is a nightmare even if it works.

Have a look at the edit

Too long for a comment
You have been very lucky to use $a=2$ for the more general case of
$$A=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{( 1+x^2) ( 1+(a+x)^2) }+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)( 1+(a-x)^2)}$$
The antiderivatives are simple after partial fraction decomposition.
To make the story short
$$4 a \left(a^2+4\right)\, A=a \left(5\pi+4 \tan ^{-1}(1-a) \right)-\log \left(\frac{((a-2)a+2)^4}{16} \right)$$
Edit
After simplification, using the relation between the exponential integrals and the trigonometric integrals
$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x y}}{y^2+1}\,dy+
\int_0^1\frac{e^{x y}}{y^2+1}\,dy$$
$$f(x)=\pi\cos(x)+\frac i2 \Big(e^{-i x} \,\text{Ei}((1+i) x)-e^{i x}\,
   \text{Ei}((1-i) x) \Big)$$
Computing
$$\large\int_0^\infty e^{-3x}\,\sin(x)\,\left[f(x)\right]^2\,dx$$ with a
WorkingPrecision=1000 leads to a difference of $2.62025\times 10^{-507}$.
Formal integration almost killed my computer.
